# Is the Disme or the Flowing Hair Dollar the considered the first official U.S coin?

Tags: currency, numismatics

The disme was first minted in 1792 but later turned in to dime with that being said the flowing hair dollar was first minted in 1794 which its size and weight were based on the Spanish dollar, vs the disme witch is one-tenth the silver weight and value of a dollar.

Comment: Please let us know what research you have done so far. Where have you looked?

Comment: When I copy/paste your question into Google, one of the first results returned is the Wikipedia page for the [Fugio cent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fugio_cent), or Franklin Cent.  That was, (as the Wikipedia page observes) "_the first official circulation coin of United States_"